# print attribute of element as string from XML file into a list

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

Im trying to parse data from an XML file. YES, i have read the official documentation, and looked at many examples. I am stuck.

The main problem is to return the data from the XML file into a string, what i'm getting now is individual characters being returned. (see output)

```
# A function to return these specific values to a list:
bookName = []
def return_book_name():
    for child in root[1][1].text:
        bookName.append(child)
return (str (bookName))
```

---

output -     ['M', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', ' ', 'R', 'a', 'i', 'n']

as you can see, I tried to return the list "bookname" as a string, but it made no difference. I also tried using STR for the child element, with the same results. I cannot get the output into the list to be a string...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please, complete your example

Comment: You dont return bookname, you are transforming the list (and its delimiter/separator) in a string. A more complete code snippet would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are iterable in Python, that is why you are getting individual characters. Just return the `text` node directly:

```
# A function to return these specific values to a list:
bookName = []
def return_book_name():
    return root[1][1].text
```

Comment: This is the exact answer! Thank you! Now i won't be *as stubborn in the future.